# Electron, how to access node API without nodeIntegration

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, security, electron

I load external content into my electron app, which has the potential to be insecure.  I want to expose an API to this unloaded content, in the form of a class.  This API class should have access to `nodeIntegration` privileges, however I do NOT want the untrusted external content to have such privileges.  The untrusted code is loaded into a [webview](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag), and the API class is loaded in the webview via [preload](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#preload).  The script loads and the class is created, it can perform all the functions I want it to without issue.  Here is the problem though, after the script finishes loading the class that I want to remain in the global scope is destroyed.  The only way for this untrusted code to access my API is if this class remains in the global scope.  **Is it possible to instantiate a class in the preloaded script that has access to nodeIntegration, and have that class be accessible by non-preloaded script files?**

Example:

Preloaded script:

```
var API = function() {
    const fs = remote.require('fs');

    API.createFile = function(){
        /*... do stuff with fs here ...*/
    }
}
```

Non-Preloaded Script (Untrusted code)

```
var instanceOfAPI = new API();

instanceOfAPI.createFile(); //should work
fs.writeFile(); //should NOT work
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57656281/289203

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the API in the window variable under the preload script.  Example:

```
var API = function() {
    const fs = remote.require('fs');

    API.createFile = function(){
        /*... do stuff with fs here ...*/
    }
}

window.api = new API();
```

The following now works in the scripts that do not have access to nodeIntegration

```
window.api.createFile() //works
fs.writeFile() //does not
```