# How to use your js files that use node.js when node integration is disabled for better security?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I made an app that reads files and displays them.

I read the docs that I should disable node integration and enable context isolation for better security and also i get a warning that electron will disable node integration by default and enable context isolation in 5.0.0.

EDIT: When node is disabled I get an error : require is not defined. My files are all required in html inside a `<script>`.

I also mention that I'm new to electron.

How can I use my files with node integration disabled?

Comment: This only applies to the render thread. You can still do whatever you want in the main thread and communicate with it through IPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use my files with node integration disabled?

If your files require Node, then you can't. Turn node integration on.

---

You should disable node integration only if you don't need Node since disabling it will reduce the attack surface. Also [Principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).

If you need to use `require` in your script, then don't disable Node integration.

That being said, you can disable node integration and supply a [preload script](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#preload) to your `webview` tag, which will let you expose specific Node APIs to that script only. (If you need to `require` modules in your file though, it sounds like you'd need to keep Node enabled).

Electron's [Security page](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security) says the following (emphasis added):

> Under no circumstances should you load and execute remote code with Node.js integration enabled. Instead, use only local files (packaged together with your application) to execute Node.js code. To display **remote content**, use the [`<webview>`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag) tag and make sure to disable the `nodeIntegration`.

Note: you should disable Node for **remote content**. If you're loading your own page, then it's fine to keep Node integration on.

Comment: I'm making a file browser, so I don't use any other websites nor internet connection, then everything is ok right?

Comment: Yeah if you're not hosting any remote content, and it's all contained within your app, you should be good

Comment: I provide a little more info about using contextIsolation etc here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57656281/289203