# Communication between preload and client given context isolation in electron

Tags: electron

I have an electron app. My client script (renderer) needs to access electron APIs, but this gave me a security warning, so I moved it into a preload script and disabled nodeIntegration. I was then receiving a warning about contextIsolation, so I enabled it. My preload script was previously attaching a function to window that the client could read as follows:

```
window.readClipboard = function(){
    return clipboard.readText()
}
```

Unfortunately, context isolation meant that the client could no longer access this function. Is there a way to make this work with context isolation or should I disable it?

**Extra Details**

The warning message that made me try to turn on context isolation was the following:

> Electron Deprecation Warning (contextIsolation default change) This
>   window has context isolation disabled by default. In Electron 5.0.0,
>   context isolation will be enabled by default. To prepare for this
>   change, set {contextIsolation: false} in the webPreferences for this
>   window, or ensure that this window does not rely on context isolation
>   being disabled, and set {contextIsolation: true}.

In client.js I try accessing:

```
console.log("window.readClipboard", window.readClipboard)
```

With output:

> window.readClipboard undefined

Comment: are you trying to access `clipboard` object from the renderer process ?

Comment: do you recall what security warning you were getting initially?

Comment: @0.sh: Yeah, I want the renderer process to be able to access the clipboard via calling a function defined in the preload script

Comment: @Casebash why can't you use do `require("electron").remote.clipboard` from the renderer process ?

Comment: @0.sh: I have the nodeIntegration setting set to false for security reasons, so I can't use require

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I see context isolation is designed to prevent the very case you described. So if you want to add data to `window` the best you can do is disable isolation.

However, I looked up the [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication) docs referred in [BrowserWindow](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) docs at the `contextIsolation` definition and find a way to use `postMessage` to get the clipboard text.

*main.js*

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

app.once('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })
  win.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
})
```

*preload.js*

```js
const { clipboard } = require('electron')

window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.source != window) return
  if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "READCLIP_REQ")) {
    window.postMessage({ type: "READCLIP_ANS", text: window.readClipboard() }, "*")
  }
}, false)

window.readClipboard = function(){
  return clipboard.readText()
}
```

*index.html*

```js
<html>
  <body>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <script>
      // Try window.readClipboard directly (works with no isolation)
      document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText =
        window.readClipboard && window.readClipboard()
      // Try the same with postMessage
      const readClipboardMessage = () => {
        window.postMessage({ type: "READCLIP_REQ" }, "*")
      }
      window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
        if (event.source != window) return
        if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "READCLIP_ANS")) {
          document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1].innerText = event.data.text
        }
      }, false)
      readClipboardMessage()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great answer @pergy.  People may also want to reference my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57656281/289203

Comment: The original question involved reading (remote) data from the clipboard. Would reading data from the clipboard imply security risks? *Writing* data from the clipboard, or otherwise loading that data, probably brings up the risks of loading remote content. But what about just reading it?